# how to resolve Arithmetic overflow error in Databricks SQL Editor

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, arithmetic-overflow

In Databricks SQL editor , I am trying to get the SUM of few 'Bigint' and 'Double' data type columns of a table. But am getting below error.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 29.0 failed 4 times, most recent 
failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 29.0 (TID 2517) (10.128.2.66 executor 3): 
org.apache.spark.SparkArithmeticException: [ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW] long overflow. If 
necessary set ansi_mode to "false" to bypass this error.
```

How to set ansi_mode from Databricks SQL editor?

I tried below in SQL editor

```
SET spark.sql.ansi.enabled = false
```

Getting below error

```
Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Configuration 
spark.sql.ansi.enabled is not available.
```

How to resolve this Arithmetic overflow error in Databricks?

Answer (score 4):

It should be just:

```sql
set ansi_mode = false;
```

See documentation for [supported configurations](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-parameters.html), and [examples for set command](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-conf-mgmt-set.html#examples).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I updated the ansi_mode value  as false through the  SET command

But the value is not getting updated . It still shows true for ansi_mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: just rechecked - works for me...